# How to use .net4.0 functions in application Which is created in .net3.5?

Tags: c#

I am working the application which is created in .net3.5 and like to use .net 4.0 functions in that . now i am using visual studio 2010 express edition .Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I find the Answer Go to Properties of particular project change the framework into 3.5 to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible.because .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 use same runtime: CLR 2.0, but .NET 4.0 use CLR 4.0.so you can't reference .net4.0 assembly in .net3.5 project.reference: [why .net2.0 project or .net3.5 project can not reference .net4.0 assembly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/clr/thread/eada8d31-5f4d-4510-9124-1edb53fc7f38).